Creating a pose in Blender 2.70 doesn't work, why?
I used Blender 2.70 normal to create poses for The Sims 4 (never had a problem), But I formatted my computer and when I installed blender 2.70 again to create poses, every time now that I enter to create pose the doll appears without color.
There is no way to create pose without facial expressions (more detailed expressions), but this of the pose only happens when I go to create pose, because when I enter Blender 2.70 without creating pose, everything is normal.
I used the windows problem detector and it says that blender 2.70 is not compatible.
How is it not compatible if I go into it normally and the colors are right?
It's only when I go to create a pose that there's a problem (which before I formatted it there was no problem at all when creating a pose).
I'VE tried 2.76, 2.79, 3.3.0, after 3.3.0 I didn't even test it anymore, because I didn't adapt to the others except 2.70)
Does anyone know how to solve it?



Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case. Also please use correct punctuation and paragraphs and avoid overly long sentences.

English is mandatory language for the site. Could you edit your post and translate all text to English? If you are not comfortable writing it yourself, feel free to use any automated online translation service.

ok thank you. ok
